# Can I send 12 volts to a 6 volt relay?

Tags: voltage, switches, relay

I currently have a 12 volt LED light strip that I would like to work with my welcome lights on my vehicle.  The system outputs 4.5 volts for the welcome lights, then it goes up to 12 volts once the door is opened.  I was thinking of using a 6 volt relay to trigger a 12 volt power source for the lights.  Once the door is opened, though, it will be sending 12 volts to the relay.  Is this too much voltage for the coil? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: The coil is rated for 6 volts. A relay can usually handle a slight overvoltage, but *double* the rated voltage will fry it very quickly. And your average 6 volt relay might not turn off if you drop the voltage to 4.5 volts. Relays are very imprecise things.

Comment: My apologies.  When the door closes and the welcome lights time out, the voltage goes to zero.  So I think the relay should turn off.  It would not be on for any ridiculous amount of time either.  Unless I leave the door open, but the vehicle times out and shuts off the light anyway. I hope this helps to clarify a little.  Also the fact that they are imprecise is what makes me think that it might work.

Comment: The relay will turn off in that condition then, yes. But just giving it 12 volts will fry it--I suggest putting a series resistor to drop the excess voltage; you can generally do that with relays.

Comment: Power dissipated by the relay coil is given by \$ \frac {V^2} R \$ so doubling the voltage will raise the power by a factor of four. When the relay coil burns out it may destroy the welcome lights dimmer. I don't recommend it.

Comment: ok.  So what options do I have then?

Comment: There are quite a few solid state relays that will work with a 3.5-32VDC input.  They have a current limiting circuit built in so you don't have to worry about changing the input voltage.

Comment: Are there any that you can recommend?

Comment: The vehicle does the voltage changing on its own.  I just want the lights to turn on when the vehicle puts out the 4.5 volts. And also not have a problem when it outputs 12 volts.

Comment: I can't recommend any specific ones (per policy and also I don't know what current your lights are drawing), but if you search Digikey, Mouser, et. al. for "solid state relay", and filter by DC output and a control voltage that covers the range you expect to see, you'll find quite a few.

Comment: I can do that.  Thank you

Comment: A 12 volt relay may not turn off if you drop it to 4.5 volts.  You should find out why that 4.5 volts is coming from.  Relays are dirt cheap, just get the right coil voltage.

Comment: Pretty sure your seeing pwm of a 12v signal. The 4.5v is an average of the multimeter since it isn't built to tell the rapid charge of the signal apart

Answer (score 1):

Other than replacing the relay with one that has a current limiter built in, you can make such a limiter yourself.

Important thing is the drop over the relay since its resistance can be approximated as constant.  You could use a switching voltage regulator and capacitor so that the relay only sees 6V max.  If the signal is indeed a PWM (put meter in AC Voltage measurement mode to check), you may be better off with this approach since it would buffer what the relay sees.

Answer (score -4):

You can put 2 identical 6V relays in series.

Comment: I would not recommend this. They won’t close and open at the same time so the slow one will take all the voltage.

Comment: @winny they will close and open at the same time since they are 2 inductors in series.

Comment: Not mechanically.

Comment: I said identical relays for a reason.

Comment: They come with production spread as standard from factory.